# Matching array value with column cell values to format worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format an exported worksheet by taking an array of team names and searching a column of sorted team names. The idea is to insert a new row above the first record of a set of team names. The problem is how do I search the column to go from bottom to top to match the value of the first value of each team.

I've tried filtering with the array values, and using a row search function to match the cell value with the array value.

```
Dim proteam As String
Dim arr() As Variant
        arr = Array("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4", "Team 5", _
              "Team 6", "Team 7", "Team 8", "Team 9")

        For Each cell In Range("A2:A214")
        If UBound(Filter(arr, cell.Value)) > -1 Or UBound(Filter(arr, cell.Value)) > -1 Then

            Rows(Cells(i, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlUp

            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
     Next
```

I keep getting an error at `Rows(Cells(i, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlUp` where it says *"Application-defined or object-defined error"*.

Comment: Use a normal For loop and loop the rows, then a second loop to loop the array and test.

Comment: `xlUp` is not a valid value for the shift parameter. You cannot insert a cell and shift the stuff up, only down or right (it's the same when you do it manually in Excel)

Comment: Or if the team names only appear once in the range, loop the array and use Range.Find or Application.Match to return the row and insert one above that.

Comment: Posted two easy solutions following Scott's suggestions; of course there are other *ways leading to Rome*.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the `I`, that's why you were getting an error. Also I have changed the `Activeworkbook.close` to a msgbox. Couln't comprehend the use of it. You can add it back if required.

Use this :

```
Dim proteam As String
Dim arr() As Variant
        arr = Array("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4", "Team 5", "Team 6", "Team 7", "Team 8", "Team 9")

        For Each cell In Range("A2:A214")
        If UBound(Filter(arr, cell.Value)) > -1 Or UBound(Filter(arr, cell.Value)) > -1 Then

            Rows(Cells(cell.Row, 1).Row).Insert 

            MsgBox "Macth Found"
        End If
     Next
```

Comment: You can't shift `xlUp`.

Comment: [`Range.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) only allows for `Shift` to be `xlShiftToRight` or `xlShiftDown`. From a quick test, it seems like the `xlUp` is ignored.

Comment: @BigBen ... I have removed it... Though i am still confused how it was working.

Comment: It seems like it's ignored. You could just as easily put `Shift:=0` or `Shift:=27` or some other bogus number.

Comment: @Mikku The code half worked but it it's a good start. The output is a newly inserted row above the first team value, and then 45 newly inserted rows beneath the first value with the rest of the values at the bottom without new rows in between.

Comment: @Adge .. Try and make it as per you want. If you face any issue, you can ask for help again.

Answer (score 0):

**Two easy example calls**

Assuming the team names only appear once in the defined data range, you could follow  @Scot's suggestion to loop through data and find matching rows, e.g. via **`Application.Match`** instead of checking each cell against the `teams` array items.

Take into account that looping through a range by VBA is time consuming; you speed it up if you loop through a data array (here: column `A1:A200`) which has been transposed to a *"flat" 1-dimensioned (and 1-based)* **array** in order to allow `match`*ing* the data.

**Further hints:** Suggest to use `Option Explicit` in any case on top of your code module to force declaration of variables and to fully qualify your range references to identify workbooks and/or worksheets correctly (otherwise you get the active sheet by Default).

**Example call 1 with insertion row by row**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestInsert()
Dim ws  As Worksheet                     ' worksheet
Dim team, teams(), data                  ' variant
Dim foundRow  As Variant                 ' important: declare as Variant to allow IsError check
Dim increment As Long
    teams = Array("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4", "Team 5", "Team 6", "Team 7", "Team 8", "Team 9")
  ' assign data in column A to array
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")                 ' << change to your sheet name
    data = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(ws.Range("A1:A200"), 0, 1)) ' assign to a "flat" array (1-based!)
    For Each team In teams                                          ' check each team
        foundRow = Application.Match(team, data, 0)                 ' try to find team occurrence in data
        If Not IsError(foundRow) Then                               ' without error a valid row has been found
          ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          ' Single insertion row by row
          ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            ws.Rows(foundRow + increment).EntireRow.Insert          ' insert entire row and ...
            increment = increment + 1                               ' add one row for each following insertion!
        End If
    Next team
End Sub
```

**Example call 2 with Insertion by one code line using `Union`**

To insert rows via `Union` (combining all needed ranges in one) has the advantage that you don't care about row increments after each new insertion and may profit from fast execution.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestIns()
Dim ws  As Worksheet                                          ' worksheet
Dim team, teams(), data                                       ' variant
Dim foundRow  As Variant                                      ' important: declare as Variant to allow IsError check
Dim rng As Range                                              ' remember all found ranges (combined via Union)
    teams = Array("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4", "Team 5", _
                  "Team 6", "Team 7", "Team 8", "Team 9")
  ' assign data in column A to array
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")           ' << change to your sheet name
    data = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(ws.Range("A1:A200"), 0, 1)) ' assign to a "flat" array (1-based!)
  ' check each team and find its row number
    For Each team In teams                                     ' check each team
        foundRow = Application.Match(team, data, 0)            ' try to find team occurrence in data
        If Not IsError(foundRow) Then                          ' a valid row has been found
            If rng Is Nothing Then                             ' first finding?
                Set rng = ws.Cells(foundRow, 1)                '      remember first cell range, e.g. A2
            Else                                               ' next findings
                Set rng = Union(rng, ws.Cells(foundRow, 1))    '      add found cell range to other findings
            End If
        End If
    Next team
  ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ' insert all found range rows at once
  ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    rng.EntireRow.Insert                                       ' insert entire rows to maintain neighbor data
End Sub
```